# Is there a way to measure flux indirectly?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astronomy, radio-frequency

Is it possible to calculate the flux of some electromagnetic radiation (say, a radio wave) using other parameters?

Comment: I answered, but realized I might have misunderstood your question. What do you mean by the "flux" of the radiation?

Answer (score 0):

If you know you're in the far field of the signal source, and you know the impedance of the transmission medium (for air or [free space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_of_free_space) it's about 377 ohms), then you could measure the electric field strength of the signal and divide by the impedance to get the magnetic field strength.